# Error when loading table from MSSQL Server to Informix DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, informix

I am trying to load a table from MSSQL - IBM Informix DB. Tables without Primary key are getting loaded but ones with Primary key are not loading and throwing following error

```
Stream component 'st_2_Informix_Target' terminated
Stream component failed at subtask 2, component st_2_Informix_Target
Error executing data handler
Handling new table 'dbo'.'region3' failed
execute create primary key failed, statement ALTER TABLE dbo.region3 ADD CONSTRAINT region3_PK__region3__3213E83F82CE48A3 PRIMARY KEY ( id )
RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: 42000 NativeError: -201 Message: [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]A syntax error has occurred.
Failed (retcode -1) to execute statement: 'ALTER TABLE dbo.region3 ADD CONSTRAINT region3_PK__region3__3213E83F82CE48A3 PRIMARY KEY ( id )'
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone (I guess SQLServer or DMS) is trying to add a primary key to the Informix table using SQLServer SQL syntax which is not valid in Informix.

```
> ALTER TABLE dbo.region3 ADD CONSTRAINT region3_PK__region3__3213E83F82CE48A3 PRIMARY KEY ( id );

  201: A syntax error has occurred.
Error in line 1
Near character position 40

> ALTER TABLE dbo.region3 ADD CONSTRAINT  PRIMARY KEY ( id ) CONSTRAINT region3_PK__region3__3213E83F82CE48A3;

Table altered.

>
```

I suggest to check if there are any options to disable PK creation when doing the load task.